# Vim search and replce

Tags: linux, vim

I want search from name_jokl_nbfg till .Q(Q_NAME). In the matched pattern, I want replace .Q(Q_NAME) to .Q(Q_NAME_NAME) and everything else should remain same.

```
ANDLVT name_jokl_nbfg( .D(NET_1),
            .S(SE_NAME),
            .Q(Q_NAME),
            .SN(SN_NAME));
```

Edits:
name_jokl_nbfg is a common string in a long instance names which are different. I want to replace Q_NAME to Q_NAME_NAME in instances containing name_jokl_nbfg only. Q_NAME is present in many other instances too. The .Q(Q_NAME) need not appear in third line only. It can appear in second or fourth line too.

Comment: :%s/.Q(Q_NAME)/.Q(Q_NAME_NAME)

Comment: I'm not clear why you emphasize `from ... till ...`? Do you want to re-connect  the `Q` pin of a cell named exactly `name_jokl_nbfg` only?

Answer (score 0):

you can visually select the range in which you want to search/replace, and then type `:`.

Vim will then add `'<,'>` (meaning "in selected range") and then you type your expression: `s/\.Q(Q_NAME)/.Q(Q_NAME_NAME)/g`

```
:'<,'>s/\.Q(Q_NAME)/.Q(Q_NAME_NAME)/g
```

Comment: Most likely not what OP wants but this is not wrong. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: I want to match from name.*.Q(Q_NAME) and replace everything with name.*.Q(Q_NAME_NAME), I need to match from name since it changes from instance to instance.

Comment: @pradeep, could you add an example of before and after, to make your question more clear.

Comment: @pradeep - better yet, add several examples. Is `Q_NAME` always two lines lower? Can it be on the same line as `name_jokl_nbfg`? Why not search for just `Q(Q_NAME)`?

Answer (score 0):

This will replace Q_NAME with Q_NAME_NAME ONLY when it occurs in a name_jokl_nbfg block.  The logic is to describe the entire multi-line block, while saving the parts into remembered groups and putting them back together with the new text in place.

```
:%s/^\(.* name_jokl_nbfg\_.\{-}\.Q(\)\(Q_NAME\)\(\_.\{-}));\)/\1Q_NAME_NAME\3/g
```

Explained:

```
:%s/   In command mode, search on every line for
^      Anchor to start of line
\(     Start first group 
.*     any number of any characters
<sp>name_jokl_nbfg    Literal string followed by
\_.    Any character including a newline
\{-}   Non-greedy version of '*' so any number of any characters including newline until...
\.Q(   Literal string
\)     End first group
\(Q_NAME\)   Second group is the literal string you want to replace
\(     Start of group 3
\_.\{-}   any number of any characters non-greedy until...
));    literal string representing the end of the block
\)     End of group 3
/      Replace all that with
\1     remembered group 1
Q_NAME_NAME  Literal string
\3     remembered group 3
/g     do that globally (omit the g if you only need to replace the first occurrence)
```